# Which partition to select for bootloader (UEFI, 2nd HDD)

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

So here is the picture of current situation -> [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuT0h.png) and I'm not sure which one to select for boot, since Windows is installed on sdb4. First time I installed I just left it on /dev/sda as it is in picture (default). Also I'm using UEFI and GPT if that means something? I tried to repair boot with boot-repair and it didn't work so I need to reinstall ubuntu again with correct place for bootloader. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the picture, installing into the MBR of either drive should be fine and grub should locate the Windows boot in /dev/sdb2 and add it to the boot list accordingly. What did you do before that didn't work? Please [edit] that information into your post. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my post, so as you can see I left it on dev/sda as it is shown in picture, should I just put it on dev/sdb? and why not on partition where EFI is? Thanks

Comment: Grub should transfer control to the PBR that your windows boot manager is on when it chainloads Windows. I would consider it safer to leave the Windows Boot manager alone.

Comment: so now I should try to set it on /dev/sdb?

Comment: Your BIOS is likely set to boot from /dev/sdb, if you set it to boot from the Toshiba terabyte drive you already installed grub on (/dev/sda) odds are good it will boot right up as is.

Comment: tried to set boot priority on Toshiba HDD but nothing happens, still booting directly into Windows

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: It does not matter what you say on where to install grub boot loader. It only installs to the ESP - efi system partition on sda. I have tried many times & every time it overwrites my /EFI/ubuntu folder on sda. If no ESP on sda, then grub will not install. Is sda gpt partitioned? If so add an ESP. If not convert to gpt with gdisk after backing up all data. Then add ESP to sda.

Comment: I think that the only ESP is on sdb as you can see it on sdb2, but I'm totally noobish in that area so not sure if that is even ESP? is there any easier ways to see if it's GPT from windows? and how can I add ESP on sda, just make new partition? sorry if I'm too noobish, you can just ignore if you feel it's too complicated